# How to map EMF model to a OSGI Device Management tree

Tags: osgi, emf

Can an EMF model be mapped and replaced by org.osgi.service.dmt?
Right now i have a emf model, so can osgi dmt provide all the functionality of EMF model?

Answer (score 0):

Given that EMF and DMT have been designed for completely different purposes, I think it is safe to answer this question with: No.